# jQuery selectors?

Tags: jquery, html

Using [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) I am trying to create a function to show and hide the DIV below the table/tr that has been clicked, but when I click in one, all the DIVs will slide up, also slide down it is not working.

I tried if `($(".container:first").is("hidden"))` but I guess is not the first element under element clicked but first element on the document.

How do I get this working?

Based on the following example.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".header").click(function(){
                    if ($(".container").is("hidden")){
                           $(".container").slideUp("slow");
                    } else {
                       $(".container").slideDown("slow");
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table class="header">
            <tr><td>Row1</td></tr>
        </table>
        <div class="container">Container 1</div>

        <table class="header">
           <tr><td>Row2</td></tr>
        </table>
        <div class="container">Container 2</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Anyone can help with how to apply the click event to the tr element inside of the table with class "header"?

Comment: Is this merely a demonstration html snippet, or are you really using single-cell tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to get only the next container, so you'd use `$.next()`:

```
$(".header").click(function(){
  $(this).next(".container").slideToggle();
});
```

Online Demo: http://jsbin.com/eyuwi3/edit

#### Updated

Requested in the comments was to make this "work on the `tr` elements." If you click *anywhere* within the table, the table's click event will eventually fire - unless a child is stopping the propagation.

If this code is not working, then your problem is elsewhere. Make sure you don't have elements between your table and your `.container` element. `$.next()` only selects immediate siblings, which is what your sample-code suggests you have.

If problems persist, you could try the following:

```
$(".header").click(function(){
  $(this).nextAll(".container:first").slideToggle();
});
```

Online Demo: http://jsbin.com/eyuwi3/2/edit

Comment: That is cool, thanks for the answer, could you also let me know how to apply to the tr element inside of the table with class "header"?

Comment: For some reason, I cant get it to work. :-(.
Thanks anyway. :-)

Comment: @CesarLopez: Please see my additions.

Answer (score 2):

Your jQuery selector are finding all `.container` divs in the document in the click handler.  Instead, use the fact that, in event handlers, `this` is set to the current event target:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".header").click(function() {
        $(this).next('div.container').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, though I've not checked, that:

```
$(this).next('div.container');
```

should work to select the element; though Jonathan's answer is the more complete.

---

**Edited in response to comments made to Jonathan's answer:**

> That is cool, thanks for the answer, could you also let me know how to apply to the tr element inside of the table with class "header"?

It depends on where the click's being detected, but assuming the click event is taken by the table cell:

```
$(this).prev('tr#header');
```

should select the `#header` table row.